# How to find boolean column value if clickableCheckBox formatter is used in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I tried Oleg clickable checkbox formatter recently posted in trirand.com forum.
Code below from other answer is used.
It finds boolean Kinnitatud column value in loadComplete.

Code below stops working with clickable checkbox formatter .

`$(row.cells[iCol]).children("input:checked").length > 0;` condition is always false
even if boolean column has value true.

How to make it work ?
It works with standard checkbox formatter.

```
{ "name":"Kinnitatud","edittype":"checkbox",
"formatter":"clickableCheckbox",
"editable":true,"width":0,"classes":null,"hidden":true,
}

var LoadCompleteHandler = function () {
    var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($grid, 'Kinnitatud'),
      cRows = $grid[0].rows.length,
      iRow,
      row,
      className,
      changeBackGround;
 for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow = iRow + 1) {
   row = $grid[0].rows[iRow];
   className = row.className;
   if ($.inArray('jqgrow', className.split(' ')) > 0) {
     // changeBackGround  is always false if formatter = "clickableCheckbox" is used:
     changeBackGround = $(row.cells[iCol]).children("input:checked").length > 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be fixed in very easy way. In the new 'clickableCheckbox' formatter the `<input>` in not direct child of the `<td>`. The cell contain is

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input disabled="disabled" value="true" checked="checked" type="checkbox" offval="no" />
    <div style="... position: absolute; zoom: 1; opacity: 0;" title="closed"></div>
</div>
```

So you should replace `$(row.cells[iCol]).children("input:checked")` to `$(row.cells[iCol]).find(">div>input:checked")`.

Comment: clickableCheckbox formatter does not take respect colmodel title parameter. If title: false is used, it still shows tooltip

Comment: @Andrus: It's clear that you should include `title: false` if you plan to set tooltip in any custom way. no formatter can change other options from `colModel`. So you have to manage all conflicts yourself.